# What can be done to increase the strength of a given electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields

There's a lot of information online about increasing the strength of an electromagnet with more turns, different cores, etc, but not much about factors in the power supply that affect the strength of the magnet.

I've got a commercial electromagnet rated for 12VDC that's supposed to produce 200 lbs of pull. What factors in the power supply will maximize this magnet's strength?

Thanks!

Comment: There is not much on the internet about factors in the power supply because there isn't any.

Comment: I think [electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this question.

Comment: Increase the number of turns of the coil, increase the amount of current.

Comment: You could just buy a better one. That will stop you having to think what factors are responsible for generating the strength of a magnet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the first thing to say is that your power supply should provide dc (direct current), though it need not be 'smooth' dc. Electromagnets don't usually work as well on ac (alternating current).

If the electromagnet itself is not to be redesigned, the only thing you can do to increase its strength is to increase the current through it. The current is proportional to the voltage (potential difference) that you apply (Ohm's law). The relationship is: current = voltage divided by electromagnet's resistance. For example if the electromagnet's resistance is 4.0 ohm, then for an applied voltage of 12 V, there will be a current through it of 3 A (3 ampere).

If you increased the applied voltage, the current would go up proportionally, and the electromagnet might – see last paragraph – pull more strongly. But there would be another consequence. More heat would be generated in the coils of the electromagnet. Suppose that you increased the voltage from 12 V to 18 V (that is by 50 %). Unfortunately the heat generated per second would go up by 125 %. [A formula for heat generated per second is voltage squared divided by resistance.] This could cause problems, even danger. It may well be that the 12 V was chosen by the manufacturers as the maximum safe voltage.

There is another point that's just occurred to me. Beyond a certain current (which may or may not be the current you get when 12 V is applied) increasing the current further will not increase the electromagnet's pull significantly. This is when the iron (or iron alloy) core of the electromagnet cannot be magnetised more strongly, an effect called 'magnetic saturation'.

Answer (score -1):

The strength of an electromagnetic field scales as (number of turns) x (number of amps). The effectiveness of the electromagnet at lifting things has to do with the layout of the pole pieces that "focus" the field into the region of space in which you want the lifting effect to be concentrated. Both ampere-turns and the pole piece design are important.

Comment: minus two for this answer??? can someone tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score -3):

More amps. Get a bigger power supply, but you risk over heating your wires and electrical arcing.

Comment: The question explicitly says that the electromagnet has a fixed voltage rating, which means that it has a fixed current it will pass. Pushing equipment past its stated limits is liable to cause damage to the equipment or a dangerous accident that can hurt both the experimenter and people around.